# How to show only one category through Javascript data-filter onLoad?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter=".my_pics"></a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".trip_pics"></a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".family_pics"></a>
```

When I load the page, all categories are showing but I want only my_pics to show. Is there a way to do this?